# Переход на поставленную метку Яндекс.Карты

Tags: javascript, яндекс-карты, яндекс-карта-api

Метка ставится, переход на метку не происходит

```
function show()
{
myMap.setCenter([57.767265, 40.925358]);
var t=document.forma1.Address.value;

ymaps.geocode(t,{results:1}).then(
function(res){  var MyGeoObj = res.geoObjects.get(0);

document.getElementById('one').value = [MyGeoObj.geometry.getCoordinates()[0], MyGeoObj.geometry.getCoordinates()[1]];
var myPlacemark = new ymaps.Placemark([MyGeoObj.geometry.getCoordinates()[0], MyGeoObj.geometry.getCoordinates()[1]]);
myMap.geoObjects.add(myPlacemark);
myMap.panTo([MyGeoObj.geometry.getCoordinates()[0], MyGeoObj.geometry.getCoordinates()[1]]);
});
}
```